# Geopandas (read_file) CRSError Message in Jupyterlab

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-lab, geopandas

I receive an error message when I try to open a shapefile in jupyterlab using geopandas.

My code:

```
import geopandas as gpd
shapefile = gpd.read_file("urban.shp")
```

### Error message:

```
CRSError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-1d7660c631f4> in <module>
      1 import geopandas as gpd
----> 2 shapefile = gpd.read_file("urban.shp")
```

.
.
.
.
.
pyproj/_crs.pyx in pyproj._crs._CRS.**init**()

```
CRSError: Invalid projection: epsg:32633: (Internal Proj Error: proj_create: SQLite error on SELECT name, coordinate_system_auth_name, coordinate_system_code, geodetic_crs_auth_name, geodetic_crs_code, conversion_auth_name, conversion_code, area_of_use_auth_name, area_of_use_code, text_definition, deprecated FROM projected_crs WHERE auth_name = ? AND code = ?: no such column: area_of_use_auth_name)
```

The prj file has the following information:

```
PROJCS["WGS_1984_UTM_Zone_33N",GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",DATUM["D_WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",500000.0],PARAMETER["False_Northing",0.0],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",15.0],PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",0.9996],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",0.0],UNIT["Meter",1.0]]
```

I reinstalled the pyproj; proj; geopanda, but the trouble stills.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your CRS definition seems OK, there should be a problem related to your environment.
Can you succesfully open shapefile in any desktop apps?

What versions of Python and Geopandas you are using?

Comment: Hi Deniz
Yes, I can open my shapefiles in other desktop apps, like ArcMap.
I am using Python 3.8 & Geopandas 0.81
Thanks for your help

Comment: I tried with similar config and didn't get any errors with same projection.